# Backbone non-default root url

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to integrate Backbone inside a `PHP CMS`.

The root url for my Backbone app is:

```
http://localhost/administrator/index.php?option=com_test&controller=product.list
```

I have setup my router like this:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'test',
    }
});

var initialize = function () {
    var router = new AppRouter;

    router.on('test', function () {
        console.log('match');
    });

    Backbone.history.start({
        pushState: true,
        root: '/administrator/index.php?option=com_test&controller=product.list'
    });

    router.navigate('/', {trigger: true});
};
```

The `navigate` function is correctly called but the route never matches. 
I tried to add a trailing backslash in the `root`, but it doesn't not change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you should either add `test` method to `Router` like that:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    '': 'test',
  },
  test: function(){
    console.log('test route');
  }
});
```

or listen to `route:test` event:

```
router.on('route:test', function () {
    console.log('match');
});
```

because `Backbone.Router` triggers routes names when matched with prefix `route:`